# how to display the first/ second .... nth latest nodes in panel/ views?

Tags: drupal, view, panels

in the panel context from existing (single)nodes? what do i put in there to retrieve only one node content, query from the latest, eg: the first latest, or the second latest or the third and so on.

Also how to do so with the views module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to show latest first, second and third node content in different areas of your page what you would do is create 3 different displays in a new view -

**first latest node content block**
order by post data DESC and in your block under Basic Settings > Items per page > change limit to 1 and leave offset at 0

**second latest node content block**
order by post data DESC and in your block under Basic Settings > Items per page > change limit to 1 and leave offset at 1

**third latest node content block**
order by post data DESC and in your block under Basic Settings > Items per page > change limit to 1 and leave offset at 2

this should work fine - might not be best way to go about it but will give you what you want - also don't forget the rest of your filters such as node type. etc

Comment: Hey Chris, where is the offset field! 

i found it! this is exactly what i'm looking. hiding in the pager settings....

Comment: sorry only just checked on here and seen you asked! sorry didn't get back to you - did you manage to sort your problem out using my suggestion?